# How to properly set rules for multilevel accounts access or permission

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my database, I have this structure.

```
{
  "agencies": {
    "a7x6BwW2GDb34sZYiLSDpzApNw03": {
      "businessInfo": {},
      "clients": {
        "V33meLCYD0Q3NATokZNBTxIH1jr2": {
          "businessInfo": {}
        },
        "uRj7uSjVfxNhwG2J5geTlkUUBtC3": {
          "businessInfo": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "b5riE7yoQEhWabFQn4ZKixTS5513": {
      "businessInfo": {},
      "clients": {
        "A0EwYmU9PLWqnJNIJJ7bvAmvn0F2": {
          "businessInfo": {}
        },
        "XO43avp90NNKo9aQSSilk0pjDvv1": {
          "businessInfo": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a rule that will allow the following:

- Each agency should have permissions to read/write each of their clients' Business Info
- Clients should have the permissions to read/write their own Business Info

And to add, each Agency and Client will be having their own login and account access.

So far, I was able to do the latter with this rule and the problem with this is the agency can't get through to its clients directory to read and write:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "agencies": {
      "$uid": {
        "businessInfo": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "clients": {
          "$uid": {
            "businessInfo": {
              ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
              ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code for the request that I've done via the simulation:

```
{
  "auth": {
    "uid": "a7x6BwW2GDb34sZYiLSDpzApNw03",
    "token": {
      "sub": "a7x6BwW2GDb34sZYiLSDpzApNw03",
      "firebase": {
        "sign_in_provider": "password"
      },
      "email": "camdevtest00@gmail.com",
      "email_verified": true
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "path": "/agencies/a7x6BwW2GDb34sZYiLSDpzApNw03/clients/V33meLCYD0Q3NATokZNBTxIH1jr2/businessInfo",
  "method": "get",
  "time": "2022-07-12T01:43:21.274Z",
  "isAdmin": false
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to reason about security rules without seeing the code that exercises them. Can you edit your question to show the code for an operation you want to allow, and one you want to disallow?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your response, I appreciate it. I've now rephrased and added more information I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you edit the question again to show the **code** for an operation you want to allow, and one you want to disallow?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, I've now added the code for the request that I've done via the Rules playground simulation. Hope it helps

Comment: That call looks like it satisfies the security rules you shared. Are you saying you get a permission_denied error on it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm getting a "Simulated read denied" on the Rules playground. What I'm aiming for is a7x6BwW2GDb34sZYiLSDpzApNw03 to be able to read/write the businessInfo under A0EwYmU9PLWqnJNIJJ7bvAmvn0F2

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work by updating the following rules:

```
  "rules": {
    "agencies": {
      "$uid": {
        "businessInfo": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "clients": {
          "$cuid": {
            "businessInfo": {
              ".read": "$uid === auth.uid || $cuid === auth.uid",
              ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || $cuid === auth.uid"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I used two different uids (`$uid` for the Agency, `$cuid` for the Client) so the rule can determine which is currently the authenticated user, and give them read/write access respectively.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good that you found it yourself , as I just spotted it too. You should indeed use different variable names (the `$` things), so that you can distinguish the two UIDs from each other.